# redirect https://www to https://no-www web config Your connection is not secure

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, redirect, http-redirect

I have this code it's work great

```
<rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

I bought the SSL certificate for one domain `https://example.com`

if the user type the domain name with **`https://www.exmple.com`**

He received this Error **Your connection is not secure**

the site can't be redirect to `https://example.com` and stay in this error.
but for other system type like `www.example.com` or `example.com` the code work well

how can I redirect before this error

maybe I need this code but in web.config I don't know how to write in web.config

```
# BEGIN SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?replace-with-your-URL\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://replace-with-your-URL.com$1 [R,L]
# END SSL
```

Comment: Does the certificate have a SAN (DNS Name) for the site with and without "www"?

Comment: Have you checked the network pane to see what it is actually being redirected to?

Comment: @vcsjones I have just  SAN for without www

Comment: @Richard yes it will work normally

Comment: With the SAN just example.com and not *.example.com then it would make sense that going to https://www.example.com gives an "unsecure" error since the certificate being used does not contain www.example.com .. certificates are very picky that way. Try generating a locally signed certificate that has www.example.com and example.com - then try the redirection. You should only get "signer not trusted" instead of "server name does not match certificate"

Answer (score 0):

The rules work with `example.com` and `www.example.com` because of the rule ordering - remove `www` then redirect to `https://` so it will be redirected to `https://example.com`

To verify this swap the rule ordering and go to `www.example.com` and you will get the `Your conection is not secure` message.

That rule will always work on non-encrypted HTTP.

SAN only example.com causes the issue here when using `https://www.example.com` because the first rule never gets executed because the browser won't allow a change since the certificate does not match the server name.

If you can get a multi-name certificate then add `www.example.com` or even better get a wildcard `*.example.com` - then anything will execute the strip www rule.

You cannot have a rule that works when the url is already encrypted unless the server name matches the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

SSL/TLS handshake happens earlier than URL rewriting, which unfortunately many people neglect.

You must present the web browser with valid certificates for both www.site.com and site.com. Otherwise, the web browser will generate a warning when it detects no valid certificate.

Either a SAN certificate with multiple host names or two certificates with proper SNI mappings should work for you, depending on your budget. With free certificates (SAN or not) from Let's Encrypt, it would be rarely a need to buy a certificate (unless you run a business with higher requirements).